# How to know if the the value of an array is composed by zeros?

Tags: c++, memory-management, arrays

Hey, if you can get a more descriptive tittle please edit it.

I'm writing a little algorithm that involves checking values in a matrix.
Let's say:

```
char matrix[100][100];
char *ptr = &matrix[0][0];
```

imagine i populate the matrix with a couple of values (5 or 6) of 1, like:

```
matrix[20][35]=1;
matrix[67][34]=1;
```

How can I know if the binary value of an interval of the matrix is zero, for example (in pseudo code)

```
if((the value from ptr+100 to ptr+200)==0){ ... // do something
```

I'm trying to pick up on c/c++ again. There should be a way of picking those one hundred bytes (which are all next to each other) and check if their value is all zeros without having to check on by one.(considering char is one byte)

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but whenever you're trying to look at `n` items, you're looking at O(n). There's no magic voodoo method for checking `n` items in less than O(n) time.

Comment: I know, but if i'm able to lower the N, the final value always drops :) precious time, i'm doing a little competition with some friends to see who's faster.

Comment: if you initialize the matrix like "char matrix[100][100];", they aren't guaranteed to all be 0. Try "char matrix[100][100] = {0};"

Comment: first, get rid of those magic numbers (100)  (ok, i know it's only an example, but never have magic numbers in real code)

Second - and I leave this to the experts to verify - I would be wary of the sort of arithmetic (or multiplication) that you are trying to use.  You can't be sure how the compiler will lay things out in memory. Say your array was 126x126, the compiler might even be tempted to reserve 128 and not use 2, sacrificing a bit of memory to gain some speed of access (etc)

Comment: Does you competition allow you to inquire for help, or are we helping you cheat? :P

Comment: *considering char is one byte* - `char` is one byte by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use std::find_if.

```
bool not_0(char c)
{
    return c != 0;
}

char *next = std::find_if(ptr + 100, ptr + 200, not_0);
if (next == ptr + 200)
    // all 0's
```

You can also use binders to remove the free function (although I think binders are hard to read):

```
char *next = std::find_if(ptr + 100, ptr + 200,
                           std::bind2nd(std::not_equal_to<char>(), 0));
```

Dang, I just notice request not to do this byte by byte.  find_if will still do byte by byte although it's hidden.  You will have to do this 1 by 1 although using a larger type will help.  Here's my final version.

```
template <class T>
bool all_0(const char *begin, const char *end, ssize_t cutoff = 10)
{
    if (end - begin < cutoff)
    {
        const char *next = std::find_if(begin, end,
           std::bind2nd(std::not_equal_to<char>(), 0));
        return (next == end);
    }
    else
    {
        while ((begin < end) && ((reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(begin) % sizeof(T)) != 0))
        {
            if (*begin != '\0')
                return false;

            ++begin;
        }

        while ((end > begin) && ((reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(end) % sizeof(T)) != 0))
        {
            --end;

           if (*end != '\0')
               return false;
        }

        const T *nbegin = reinterpret_cast<const T *>(begin);
        const T *nend = reinterpret_cast<const T *>(end);

        const T *next = std::find_if(nbegin, nend,
           std::bind2nd(std::not_equal_to<T>(), 0));
        return (next == nend);
    }
}
```

What this does is first checks to see if the data is long enough to make it worth the more complex algorithm.  I'm not 100% sure this is necessary but you can tune what is the minimum necessary.

Assuming the data is long enough it first aligns the begin and end pointers to match the alignment of the type used to do the comparisons.  It then uses the new type to check the bulk of the data.

I would recommend using:

```
all_0<int>(); // 32 bit platforms
all_0<long>(); // 64 bit LP64 platforms (most (all?) Unix platforms)
all_0<long long>() // 64 bit LLP64 platforms (Windows)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in language feature to do that, nor is there a standard library function to do it.  [`memcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp) could work, but you'd need a second array of all zeroes to compare against; that array would have to be large, and you'd also eat up unnecessary memory bandwidth in doing the comparison.

Just write the function yourself, it's not that hard.  If this truly is the bottleneck of your application (which you should only conclude of **profiling**), then rewrite that function in assembly.

Answer (score 1):

you tagged this C++, so you can use a pointer as an iterator, and use an stl algorithm. std::max. Then see if the max is 0 or not.

Comment: On platforms where char is signed, this can fail if all the non-0 char's have the high bit set.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast your pointer as an `int *` and then check four bytes at a time rather than one.

Comment: i thought about doing it to double or for even more bytes

Comment: Except that you need to guarantee that `0.0` is indeed stored as all-bits zero. Plus now you have potential alignment problems on some processors.

Comment: Don't use doubles, you'll get a huge performance penalty from the integer/floating-point conversions.  If you use long longs instead, you might get more performance on a 64-bit processor, though.

Comment: Why four (sorry, not clear))? What is an "interval"? Is it a single entry, or a range? If a range, parametrize it.

Comment: On most platforms, `int` is four bytes. When actually implementing this, you would of course use `sizeof(int)` when determining how many checks you need to do instead of just guessing 4.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to tell whether an array has any value other than zero other than by checking all elements one by one. But if you start with an array that you know has all zeros, then you can maintain a flag that states the array's zero state.

```
std::vector<int> vec(SIZE);
bool allzeroes = true;

// ...

vec[SIZE/2] = 1;
allzeroes = false;

// ...

if( allzeroes ) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reserve element 0 of your array, to be set to all zeros.

Use memcmp to compare the corresponding ranges in the two elements.